# Multi Domain ssl certificates - Single IP or multiple IP's

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have a server with multiple IP addresses, Each address hosts a single website, Each website has a different domain name ( the company has a few divisions, each with its own branding)

Will a multi domain certificate work in this case?

Do multi-certs mean 1 ip with many domains? or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use one cert (as long as it includes all the various domains). You only need 1 IP (per physical server) for this type of setup too.

Comment: Thanks, but one of the requirements is that each domain has it own IP, this wont be a problem, right?

Comment: that should be fine, when you configure the Binding for each site you can specify the specific IP you want each site bound to.

Answer (score 0):

the best case scenario is to have separate FQDN assign to separate IP address with separate certificate this is where you get the most compatibility with older browsers.

there are ways to have it configure on one IP, but only new browsers would be able to work with that without throwing you warnings.